# Create partition button greyed out during installation

Tags: partitioning, system-installation

I can't create a partition during the installation of Ubuntu on my laptop.
When choosing the corresponding drive, the button for partitioning is simply greyed out.

[image: picture of it]

I it is, however, enabled, when i select other drives.

Of course, no effing error message or explanation on the GUI on this whatsoever.

Comment: Trying to read the out of focus image gives me a headache.  Can you try to send another image?  You might consider taking a couple and uploading the best.  The blurriness is most likely from moving while clicking.

Comment: Blurry image is blurry, but I believe that your `/dev/sdb` is already set up as the mount point for `/` if I'm reading this right.  Can you take a new picture/screenshot that is less blurry and more in-focus?

Answer (score 2):

As it turns out, this error occured because the device was already mounted.
After i aborted the installation, i got booted into a Linux-Live-System, from which i was able to restart the installation. Only this time, a nice message box told me that a certain drive was already mounted and, in order to partition it, it needed to unmount it. Which it did. After that, it worked..